# Emacs sometimes fails to save files

Tags: microsoft-windows, debugging, saving

I'm experiencing a weird problem with Emacs on Windows where sometimes, after a while, the current buffer I'm in throws an error when attempting to save the file. I can't seem to reliably reproduce the issue (since when I first open the file, it saves fine and even for a few times after that), but after working on it for a while, suddenly I'll get an error when attempting to save the file. The only resolution is to restart Emacs; simply killing and re-opening the buffer has no effect. Turning on `toggle-debug-on-error` gives me the following:

`Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Opening output file" "invalid argument" "c:/Users/sonictk/Git/experiments/opengl_test/main.cpp")
  write-region(nil nil "c:/Users/sonictk/Git/experiments/opengl_test/main.cpp" nil t "~/Git/experiments/opengl_test/main.cpp")
  basic-save-buffer-2()
  basic-save-buffer-1()
  basic-save-buffer()
  save-buffer(1)
  call-interactively(save-buffer nil nil)
  command-execute(save-buffer)`

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this further since these seem to be built-in functions; could anyone provide any advice on how best I should proceed?

I tried turning on `debug-on-entry` for `write-region` for a file that doesn't seem to have the issue compared with a file that does, and I couldn't see any difference passed to the function calls

```
This works:

write-region(nil nil "c:/Users/sonictk/Git/experiments/opengl_test/shaders/vert.glsl" nil t "~/Git/experiments/opengl_test/shaders/vert.glsl")

Somehow, this doesn't, after a while:

- write-region(nil nil "c:/Users/sonictk/Git/experiments/opengl_test/main.cpp" nil t "~/Git/experiments/opengl_test/main.cpp")
  ```

I can't understand it; what could be the issue?

UPDATE: As usual, I find the answer only after giving up after a few hours and posting on the interwebs; turns out `irony-mode` was keeping an open file handle to the file in question for some reason which prevented anything (not just Emacs) from overwriting the file. Now I just have to figure out why irony is behaving the way it is only with this file in particular.

Comment: Are you using the latest stable release of Emacs for Windows; i.e. **25.3**?

Comment: @lawlist I'm currently on GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570. I'm a little skeptical that it's the Emacs version specifically, since this seems to happen only with this file for some reason that I haven't quite managed to figure out yet. I could try upgrading, but I'd prefer for that to be a last resort.

Comment: I had the same problem using `C-x C-w` with the same name worked for me. I've also had this issue when I've had opened Notepad++ but not the file I was saving in Emacs and closing Notepad++ solved the issue.

Comment: Since today I'm also experiencing a similar issue... I'm using doom on Linux, and in my case just one buffer gets crazy (a LaTeX one for me): I can't save (even in a new file), can't kill the buffer, it displays when I try to save a "waiting" mouse cursor that diseapear when I C-g, but I can continue typing, change the modes, create and save other buffers (including at the same path)... I'm using emacs 27.1. Did you understood what was wrong?

Comment: @tobiasBora I had a similar issue today and found out that the emacs lock file (the .#filename file), for some reason, was created with a different user (admin) than my user. As soon as I removed it, everything went back to normal.

Comment: @nonDucor Actually, I found the issue: the issue is from undo tree. See report https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/4640 and some solutions here https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/1407. Unfortunately, in my case non of them actually worked, so when the bug occurs I just disable & re-enable undo-tree.

Comment: if I have `git diff` open while saving a file with a diff, this happens.

from your prompt it looks like you're editing source code in git, so maybe you were diffing it at the time.

Comment: This usually happens when a file is locked by another process. E.g. when the file is open by another program in Windows. See https://superuser.com/questions/140643/how-to-get-the-names-of-the-programs-which-are-accessing-a-certain-file-folder-a for suggestion on how to find out which program is accessing the file in question.