# Emacs freezes when saving org file in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, files, saving

For some reason I cannot save files while in org-mode. This happened after I updated to a most recent version of org-mode. If I change to text mode I can save without a problem. I have tried `C-x C-w` to write it to the same file and it hangs endlessly as well. Other modes (tex, python) seem to save without problems. This is the only vaguely related [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37833/emacs-sometimes-fails-to-save-files). Is there any way to debug the problem? Thanks.

My Org-mode version is 9.2 and emacs is 25.2.2.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I did another upgrade of org-mode and now it works. Must have been a local bug. Thanks for your help @choroba